# Error during taking picture

Tags: android

I'm writing an application which have to take a picture and send it to a web service.
There is the code I use to :

```
i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/appicture.jpg"));
Log.i("URI", outputFileUri.toString());
i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
startActivityForResult(i, cameraData);
```

The URI looks like :

> file:///sdcard/appicture.jpg

But if I put "outputFileUri" var in the i.putExtra, my app just quit.
If not, I can take the picture but I can't get her URI then unable to send it to my webservice.

EDIT 1 :
Error log ( on the activity resylt)

> 06-26 09:17:46.108: I/Cam error(699): java.lang.NullPointerException

EDIT 2 :
If I remove the "outputFileUri", I correctly got the Image. But, then I'm unable to convert the Bitmap into File to be able to send it.

```
if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){

            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            _bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data"); 

        }
```

EDIT 3 :

The problem was from

> _bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");

And the picture is correctly save in the sd card.

Comment: WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission?

Comment: @David : you have try as `outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile( new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "appicture.jpg"));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add **WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** permission in Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

**EDIT:**
 if you are passing Image Uri in Intent for Capturing image then get image as in `onActiityResult` as:

```
@Override  
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {    
        if (requestCode == cameraData) {  
            File picture = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/appicture.jpg"); 
            Uri imguri=Uri.fromFile(picture);
            }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);  
    }
```

and if you want to get image as data in `onActiityResult` then Launch Camra as:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);  
startActivityForResult(intent, cameraData);
```

in onActivityResult:

```
 onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
        if (requestCode == 1) {  
            if (resultCode == cameraData) {  
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                _bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data"); //Get data here

            }  
        }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please add this in Manifest File

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

Happy Coding..

Answer (score 1):

If you already added the permissions and the path is correct. Could you please try removing ".jpg" at the end of your path